# How to fix snap "Brave" Warning

Tags: snap, brave

~$ WARNING: There is 1 new warning. See 'snap warnings'.

```
~$ snap warnings

 last-occurrence:  today at 12:03 PKT
warning: |
  snap "brave" has bad plugs or slots: content (content plug must contain target
  path)
```